# Como puedo relacionar 2 valores diferentes en un solo contador

Tags: javascript, dom

Estoy desarrollando un contador para una web en donde uno de sus requisitos es que posea un contador en donde el cliente pueda elegir un plan de megas personalizado

En cuando al contador no tuve mucho problema

Mi problema es que al lado de la cantidad de megas a contratar debo agregar su correspondiente precio

Al querer agregarlo al contador me encontré que no puedo relacionar correctamente la cantidad de megas con el precio

Adjunto el código que hice hasta ahora :

```
// Creacion del Contador de Megas

let contador = 1;
let contador2 = 100;
const valor = document.querySelector('#valor');
const botones = document.querySelectorAll('.boton');
const valor2 = document.querySelector('#valor2');

botones.forEach(boton =>{
    boton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        const estilos = e.currentTarget.classList;

        if(estilos.contains('disminuir')){
            contador--;
            contador2= contador2-contador2;
        }
        else if(estilos.contains('aumentar')){
            contador++;
            contador2= contador2+contador2;
        }
        else if(estilos.contains('resetear')){
            contador = 1;
            contador2 = 200;
        }
        valor.textContent =contador;
        valor2.textContent=contador2;

        //Manejo de Excepciones menos al numero 0

        if(contador >=1){
            valor.style.color = '#acb134'; 
        }
        if(contador <1 ){
            valor.style.color = '#ba215a';     
             Swal.fire({
                text:"Seleccione un numero mayor o igual a 1",
                icon:  "warning",
                allowOutsideClick: false,
            });
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que se soluciona usando 'target', en lugar de 'currentTarget':

```
const estilos = e.target.classList;
```